# Xcode 3 can't open interface builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, sdk, builder

In Xcode 3, if I double click an xib file, it doesn't open it with interface builder. It does absolutely nothing. How can I solve this ? I have Xcode 3 with iPhone SDK 4.0.2 installed.

Comment: Worst case scenario, reinstall everything.

Comment: What version of xcode are you using? If using xcode 4, there is no more interface builder and the interface file open right in xcode

Comment: It's xcode 3.2.3 with iphone sdk 4.0.2

Comment: It's also happening on XCode 13 for me 

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem in a new Mac or sdk installation. Try opening the Interface builder app first. When it is open, try opening your xibs.

Answer (score 0):

Try rightclicking the .xib and selecting open or open with.

Maybe it could work that way.

Comment: Can you open the IB App itself?

Comment: Or rightclick and then select open as then Xcode.IDEKit.CocoaTouchIntegration.EditorDocument.CocoaTouch-title

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you double click the .xib. If not Click the interface builder icon in the dock at bottom after you double clicked the .xib.